# React: nextProps and state are always same; hence component won't re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am stuck in a weird situation.

I have a component that is used for both, presenting an info and editing that info as well. Due to this situation, I have to maintain a copy of this information in my component's state( the information is passed down to the component through props, I am using Redux ).

However, the situation is if I am trying to update something, **my component isn't re-rendering**. The reason for that is **my nextProps and current state are always the same**.

I am not mutating my state directly, here are my component and container. I added `componentShouldUpdate` to check whether it is processing sate updates properly. I logged the nextProps and state and those two are always the same.

**Component**

```
export class SingleSpacePartner extends Component  {
  state = {
    spacePartner: {}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getSpacePartner();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, state) {
    console.log(nextProps, state);
    return true;
  }

  toggleAccount = (value)=> {
    const spacePartner = {...this.state.spacePartner, active: value};
    this.setState({spacePartner});
  }

  handleChange = (e)=> {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const spacePartner = {...this.state.spacePartner, [name]: value};
    console.log(spacePartner);
    this.setState({spacePartner});
  }

  getSpacePartner = ()=>{
    let id = this.props.match.params.id;
    const handleSuccess = ({data})=>{
      return this.props.getSingleSpacePartnerSuccess(data);
    };
    return this.props.getSingleSpacePartner(id).payload.then(handleSuccess).catch(err => err);
  }

  updateSpacePartner = (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {spacePartner} = this.state;

    spacePartner.centers = spacePartner.centers.map(el => el._id);

    this.props.updateSpacePartner(spacePartner._id, spacePartner).payload.then(this.getSpacePartner).catch(err => err);
  }

  render() {
    let { spacePartner } = this.state;
    let { loading } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className='single_space_partner_page'>
        <SidebarContainer activeRoute='spacePartner'/>
        {Object.keys(spacePartner).length ?
            <div className='single_space_partner_wrapper'>
              <EditSpacePartner value={spacePartner} toggleAccount={this.toggleAccount} updateSpacePartner={this.updateSpacePartner} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>

              // rest of the template

            </div>
            : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Container**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // actions
});

const mapStateToProps = ({ spacePartner: spacePartnerState }) => {
  let {spacePartner, loading, error} = spacePartnerState;

  return {
    spacePartner,
    loading,
    error
  };
};


export const SingleSpacePartnerContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SingleSpacePartner);
```

Another thing that is weird is that say my Spacepartner has a title. The current value is `My Title`, and if I remove `e` from it then the change propagated is `{title: 'My Titl'}` and of course the view isn't re-rendered. However, if I remove `l` as well, then still the propagated change is `{title: 'My Titl'}`.

What could be the reason for all this?

Thank you.

**Edit: Here's my EditSpacePartner component**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Toggle} from '../common/Toggle/Toggle';

export const EditSpacePartner = ({value, toggleAccount, updateSpacePartner, handleChange}) => {
  return (
    <div className='edit_space_partner'>
      <h2>Space Partner</h2>
      <form onSubmit={updateSpacePartner}>
        <div className='form_wrapper'>
          <div className='edit_name_wrapper'>
            <label htmlFor=''>Name</label>
            <input type='text' name='name' value={value.name} onChange={handleChange}/>
          </div>
          <div className='edit_product_key_wrapper'>
            <label>Status</label>
            <Toggle value={value.active} toggle={toggleAccount}/>
          </div>
          <div className='edit_name_wrapper'>
            <label htmlFor=''>Sample</label>
            <input type='text' readOnly name='name' value={value.sample || false}/>
          </div>
          <input type='submit' className='submit'/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: where are you updating component state based on props, also the mapStateToProps data will come to component as props, why don't you directly use it instead of keeping a local state

Comment: Where are you using redux anyway?

Comment: spacePartner is an object and you are mutating it. If you mutate it there won't be any comparision. Use Object.assign() for changing any value of an object.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri because `EditSingleSpacePartner` serves both as displaying the info and as well as editing it. So I can't connect it to redux and update redux store for every character change that would be a disaster. Hence, I keep a local copy, and once the user submits the changes, the redux store is updated.

Comment: Can you paste `EditSpacePartner` component?

Comment: @Bhupendra done

Comment: Things are working fine for me with above code.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove below code then it will solve your problem.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, state) {
    console.log(nextProps, state);
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: I placed just to debug, to check how React was handling my state changes

Answer (score 0):

spacePartner is an object and you are mutating it. If you mutate it there won't be any comparision. Use Object.assign() for changing any value of an object. Immutability is what helps compare props/nextProps and state/nextState.